# Why would one specify multiple arguments when using get_previous_posts_link() which takes only one parameter?

Tags: plugin-development, functions, links, previous-post-link

I'm looking at some plugin code that looks like so:

`get_previous_posts_link(__('<span>&larr;</span> Newer', 'gc-sermons'), $total_pages`

When I look at the [WP function reference for get_previous_post_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_previous_posts_link/) I see that it is defined with only one parameter like so:

`get_previous_posts_link( string $label = null )`

The first argument passed makes sense with above parameter:

`__('<span>&larr;</span> Newer', 'gc-sermons')`

But what is the second argument (`$total_pages`) for? Is there any reason to retain it?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason for it to be there, and it won't do anything. Only the author would know why it's there, but it's likely a mistake.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/207362)

Comment: The question was "But what is the second argument ($total_pages) for? Is there any reason to retain it?" I've answered it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)